# Use the signal of an already instanced module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have some blocks, designed by another person (core.sv and others), which I can not modify and I need a value for two different files.

Can I instantiate "core.sv" in both (riscv_top_tb.sv and tracelog.sv)?

This is my TestBench file: riscv_top_tb.sv

```
genvar r;
generate
  for (r = 1; r < 32; r++) begin : gen_mprf_assign   
    assign rv_vip_rf_if.x[r] = RISK_V.bancoDeRegistros.bancoReg[r];
  end : gen_mprf_assign
endgenerate


//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Core instance
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
core #(.RamSize(RamSize)) RISK_V 
    (
        .CLK(CLK),
        .RESET_N(RESET_N),
        .IMEM_DIR(dir_rom),
        .IMEM_DATA(data_rom),
        .DMEM_DIR(dir_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_R(dataR_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_W(dataW_ram),
        .I_READ(I_READ),
        .D_READ(D_READ),
        .D_WRITE(D_WRITE)
    );
```

And this is my tracelog file: tracelog.sv

```
core #(.RamSize(RamSize)) RISK_V 
    (
        .CLK(CLK),
        .RESET_N(RESET_N),
        .IMEM_DIR(dir_rom),
        .IMEM_DATA(data_rom),
        .DMEM_DIR(dir_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_R(dataR_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_W(dataW_ram),
        .I_READ(I_READ),
        .D_READ(D_READ),
        .D_WRITE(D_WRITE)
    );

assign mprf_int_alias.INT_00_ZERO   = '0;
assign mprf_int_alias.INT_01_RA     = RISK_V.bancoDeRegistros.bancoReg[1];
assign mprf_int_alias.INT_02_SP     = RISK_V.bancoDeRegistros.bancoReg[2];
```

If this is not possible, how should I do it?

Comment: What is the particular problem with this code? Normally you should be able to create as many instances as you want.

Comment: Also, you do not instantiate files, you instantiate modules. Each instance of a module replicates all declarations inside that module.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it very much sounds like you're trying to copy the file in both TB and tracelog. In that case, you can simply do

```
`include "risk_v_instantiation.sv"
```

where the "risk_v_instantiation.sv" file has the text:

```
core #(.RamSize(RamSize)) RISK_V 
    (
        .CLK(CLK),
        .RESET_N(RESET_N),
        .IMEM_DIR(dir_rom),
        .IMEM_DATA(data_rom),
        .DMEM_DIR(dir_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_R(dataR_ram),
        .DMEM_DATA_W(dataW_ram),
        .I_READ(I_READ),
        .D_READ(D_READ),
        .D_WRITE(D_WRITE)
    );
```

You still have to handle signal declarations which you may be able to add to this file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate a **file** anywhere. You can instantiate a **module**. A module can be instantiated inside another **module**. This way you build a *hierarchy* of module **instances**.

There is always a top-level module(s) which is not instantiated by anything else, or defined by other means. Your hierarchy starts with this module and branches down to other instances.

Testbench is usually instantiated as a part of this hierarchy (though it might have its own top).

You can instantiate the same module in different hierarchies or multiple times in the same hierarchy (varying instance names).

From a test bench you can access variables in any part of the hierarchy, using cross-module-references (xmr). You just need to provide the hierarchy path to the instance you are interested int.

So, answering your question: yes, you can instantiate the same `core` **module** in different hierarchies. However there will be 2 different instances with in different levels of hierarchy with their own inputs, outputs, variables, and parameters. They will have different instance paths (despite that you name the local instances the same) and will require different xmr access paths to their internals.